# Git file history as if all merges were rebases

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to list individual commits for a file in `main` - ignoring merge commits - in the order they were *applied*, not the order they *occurred*.

For example, consider this git history for a file:

```
0    Merge Commit
|\
0 |  Main Commit 2
| |
| 0  Branch Commit
|/
0    Main Commit 1
```

I would like to see

```
Branch Commit
Main Commit 2
Main Commit 1
```

.. where `Branch Commit` is top, because even though it was committed earlier, the change was only applied to `main` *after* `Main Commit 1` and `Main Commit 2`.

In short, I would like a straight-line history of a file as if all merges were, instead, rebases.

---

### What I have tried:

`git log --no-merges -- {file}` gets me close, but the commits are shown in chronological order:

```
Main Commit 2
Branch Commit
Main Commit 1
```

.. which is not the order that the changes were applied.

I also tried `git log --first-parent`, but I think I'll only see the merges and lose the individual commits on a branch.

Note: I'm doing this in code, so if the only option is recursively following merge commit parents, that is an option.

Comment: `git log` has a few options related to commit order..... Did you check them already? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering

Comment: Yeah I couldn't see anything, but it's possible I'm missing something.`--topo-order` is close but I don't think it guarantees which branch's commits appear first

Comment: From `main`'s point of view, technically each merge commit and all of the commits it brings in are applied *simultaneously*. From there one could argue that the `--first-parent` view, although missing some commits, is actually sufficient as to what was applied, and in what order.

Comment: `--first-parent` does give a correct history in the right order, for the reason you said (all commits in a merge are applied at once). My issue is that in our workflow, `main`is just a series of merge commits. I was hoping to 'expand' those merges for better resolution on individual changes (I e. as if we rebased on to master, instead of always merging)